# Add a counter to display on each email title, and reset after 24hs

Tags: powershell

I have a script that sends an email if a file is received in a folder. I tried to make a counter that should add +1 every email sent (Should start with 1). I tried with counter++ with do + while loops but it did not worked right. How i can do this?

```
$time = get-date -Format HH:mm:ss

if($time -ge "00:00:00"){

$Contador = 1

..\US\Desktop\automail.ps1 $Contador

}
```

And the principal script has the new counter after a email is sent. But it just gets into a infinite loop like this...

```
$time = get-date -Format HH:mm:ss

if($time -lt "06:00:00"){

#do nothing 

}

else {

send email

$Contador++

    }
```

Maybe i missing to indicate the variable to where the new counter value is going to be saved? I'm trying everything right now!

Comment: Does `automail.ps1` check for the file, or does it just send the email?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it has a sourcedir and destdir to copy-item to a new folder where the attachment will be taken from.